# How to get minimum LocalDateTime from array in Java

Tags: java, arrays, minimum

I have an array:

`LocalDateTime[] onTimes`

I would like to find an efficient way (without iteration) of finding the minimum LocalDateTime.

Is there a quick way to do this?

Comment: If you want to get the minimum element of an unsorted array, you need to check each element. If you need to do it faster, use a different data structure (min heap, tree, whatever) pr make sure the array is sorted.

Comment: I think that you're trying to solve an unsolvable problem in computer science... if you have an unsorted array with N elements, you have to check all N elements to decide what is the minimal value. You can minimize this operation using all sorts of data structures and / or sorts depending on your needs

Comment: `Collections.min(Arrays.asList(onTimes))`. Throws an exception if the array has length 0 or contains a `null`, so you should first make sure it doesn’t.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could, conceivably, use recursion; but I would not recommend that for performance. The best way I can think of is using the streams api like

```
LocalDateTime min = Arrays.stream(onTimes).min(Comparator.naturalOrder())
        .orElseThrow();
```

Note: This still iterates all elements internally to find the minimum.

For completeness sake; to do this without iteration, as I said, might be done recursively.

```
public static LocalDateTime getMinimum(LocalDateTime[] onTimes) {
    return getMinimum(onTimes, 0);
}

private static LocalDateTime getMinimum(LocalDateTime[] onTimes, int i) {
    if (i + 1 < onTimes.length) {
        return min(onTimes[i], getMinimum(onTimes, i + 1));
    } else {
        return onTimes[i];
    }
}

private static LocalDateTime min(LocalDateTime a, LocalDateTime b) {
    if (a.compareTo(b) <= 0) {
        return a;
    }
    return b;
}
```

Comment: Note that this also checks all elements and it essentially just hides the iteration.

Comment: Hmmm, streams are something I need to look into a little more. While it does "hide" the iteration, it looks a hell of a lot better!

Comment: @ElliottFrisch what is Comparator?

Comment: @JoshuaCastelino [`java.util.Comparator`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html).